# The structure of the rationals in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

If we take any nonempty interval in $\mathbb{R}$, no matter how small, will there always be rational numbers contained within it?  Or are there stretches in $\mathbb{R}$ consisting of only irrational numbers?

I know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable and $\mathbb{R}$ is uncountable, but if it's true that for any two irrationals there are infinitely many rational numbers in between, it seems like the difference between countable and uncountable is very subtle.

Comment: Yes, betwen any two real numbers $a<b$ there always a rational number $r$ between them, i.e. $a<r<b$.

Comment: Some finite-decimal truncation over their average is between a and b.

Answer (score 2):

Any interval in $\mathbb{R}$ contains an open interval. Since an open interval is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ in the usual topology, and $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ under this same topology, it follows that $\mathbb{Q}$ has non-trivial intersection with our open inteveral. Hence there is at least one rational number in any interval. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_approximation

Answer (score 2):

This is true.  To see it, suppose we arbitrarily select any two $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.  Notice that we can always find an $n$ such that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{n} < |x-y|$.  If we then consider the multiples $k(1/n)$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, you can see that at least one such multiple will lie between $x$ and $y$.

Once you have this first rational $q \in [x, y]$, you can repeat the above process a second time by first finding an $m$ such that $\displaystyle \frac{1}{m} < |q - y|$.  This will yield a second rational in this interval.  Repeat *ad infinitum*, and you arrive at an infinite number of rationals inside the given interval.

---

Alternatively, once you have two rationals inside of the interval, you can generate infinitely many more by doing successive arithmetic means.